# Why is my lockscreen in French?

Tags: greeter

For some reason my lockscreen/sign in screen has changed the clock/calendar format to French and I am unable to find any settings for it. The desktop is in English and the clock and calendar are in the formats I set them at. It wasn't until after a recent update (after sunday) that this happened. Has anyone else experienced this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to **Settings** -> **Language and Region**
Now you should see a window with the actual settings of language.
On the **right top corner** there is an **unlock button**. Press it and enter your password.
After this it should be possible to set the correct Language and Region.

Then restart the system.

Comment: @michael; Thanks but I had already done that, after the update the system language was in French, so I did change back to English, however the language of the calendar is still in French and I haven't found a way to change it.

Comment: @ZenSurfer Mhh, can you try to set the location in Date and Time to an different one. I can remember that there was a bug somewhere related to wrong Time setting (12 and 24 hours were displayed wrong in lock screen). Otherwise try to reinstall language packs

Comment: @michael Thank you for your help, I will see if that helps